# Erro ao executar função pela segunda vez

Tags: hibernate, java-ee, jsp

Dentro do controller tenho está função:

```
public void salvaEncaminhamento() {
    Integer qtdEncaminhamento = 0;

    if (manifestacao.getTbEncaminhamentoCollection() != null) {
        qtdEncaminhamento = manifestacao.getTbEncaminhamentoCollection().size();
    }

    TbUsuario usuario = securityService.getUser();
    for(String idUnidadeStr : idOrgaoDestino) {
        try {
            int idUnidade = Integer.parseInt(idUnidadeStr);

            //atualiza data de modificacao da manifestacao
            manifestacao.setDtUltimaAtualizacao(new Date());
            //atualiza status da manifestacao caso ela ainda esteja como nova
            if (manifestacao.getStStatusManifestacao().equals(StatusManifestacaoEnum.EM_ANALISE.getId()) || manifestacao.getStStatusManifestacao().equals(StatusManifestacaoEnum.SOLICITACAO_RESPONDIDA.getId())) {
                manifestacao.setStStatusManifestacao(StatusManifestacaoEnum.EM_ANDAMENTO.getId());
                dao.edit(manifestacao);
            }

            /*-----------------------------------------------------*/
            /*------- inicio - gravando encaminhamento ------------*/
            /*-----------------------------------------------------*/
            TbEncaminhamento encaminhamento = new TbEncaminhamento();
            encaminhamento.setDsDescricao(dsEncaminhamento);
            encaminhamento.setDtCriacaoEncaminhamento(new Date());
            encaminhamento.setDtEnvioTramite(new Date());
            encaminhamento.setIdManifestacao(manifestacao);
            encaminhamento.setIdUsuarioEnviou(usuario);
            encaminhamento.setIdUnidadeEnviou(usuario.getIdUnidade());
            encaminhamento.setStEncaminhamento(StatusEncaminhamentoEnum.ENCAMINHADA.getId());

            TbUnidade unidade = unidadeDAO.find(idUnidade);
            encaminhamento.setIdUnidadeRecebeu(unidade);

            encaminhamentoDAO.create(encaminhamento);
            qtdEncaminhamento++;
            /*------- fim - gravando encaminhamento ------------*/


            /*-----------------------------------------------------*/
            /*------- inicio - gravando tramite -------------------*/
            /*-----------------------------------------------------*/
            TbTramite tramite = new TbTramite();
            tramite.setDsDescricao(dsEncaminhamento);
            tramite.setDtTramite(new Date());
            tramite.setIdEncaminhamento(encaminhamento);
            tramite.setIdUnidadeEnvio(unidade);
            tramite.setIdUsuarioEmissor(usuario);
            tramite.setStRetornada(BooleanEnum.NAO.getId());
            tramite.setStNotificacao(BooleanEnum.NAO.getId());
            tramite.setStTramitePublico(BooleanEnum.NAO.getId());

            TbUsuario usuarioReceptor = null;
            if (ValidacaoHelper.isNotEmpty(idUsuarioEncaminhamento)) {
                usuarioReceptor = usuarioDAO.find(idUsuarioEncaminhamento);
                tramite.setIdUsuarioReceptor(usuarioReceptor);
            }
            tramiteDAO.create(tramite);

            //----- gravando anexos ---------//
            ArrayList<TbTramitexAnexo> anexosTramite = new ArrayList<>();
            for (TbAnexo anexo : arquivosEncaminhamento) {
                anexoDAO.create(anexo);
                TbTramitexAnexo tbTramitexAnexo = new TbTramitexAnexo();
                tbTramitexAnexo.setIdAnexo(anexo);
                tbTramitexAnexo.setIdTramite(tramite);
                anexosTramite.add(tbTramitexAnexo);
            }
            tramite.setTbTramitexAnexoCollection(anexosTramite);
            tramiteDAO.edit(tramite);
            /*------- fim - gravando tramite ------------*/

            try {
                enviarEmailsEncaminhamento(unidade, usuarioReceptor);
                //----- enviando e-mail ao MANIFESTANTE ---------//
                if (qtdEncaminhamento == 1) {
                    EmailService.Email emailManifestante = emailService.newEmail();
                    if ((manifestacao.getEeEmailUsuario() != null) && "1".equals(manifestacao.getStResposta())) {

                        String nomeManifestante = (manifestacao.getNmPessoa() != null) ? manifestacao.getNmPessoa() : "Manifestante";
                        emailManifestante.addDestinatario(nomeManifestante, manifestacao.getEeEmailUsuario());

                        TbEmailAutomatizado emailAutomatizado = emailAutomatizadoDAO.findByTipo(EmailAutomatizadoEnum.PRIMEIRO_TRAMITE);

                        //adiciona texto e assunto de email padrao
                        StringBuilder emailTextoHtml = new StringBuilder();
                        StringBuilder emailTexto = new StringBuilder();

                        emailManifestante.setAssunto(PalavrasChavesHelper.converterPalavrasChaves(emailAutomatizado.getNmTituloEmail(), manifestacao, false));
                        emailTextoHtml.append(PalavrasChavesHelper.converterPalavrasChaves(emailAutomatizado.getDsEmail(), manifestacao, false));
                        emailTexto.append(PalavrasChavesHelper.converterPalavrasChaves(emailAutomatizado.getDsEmail(), manifestacao, false));

                        emailManifestante.setTextoHtml(emailTextoHtml.toString());
                        emailManifestante.setTextoSemFormatacao(emailTexto.toString());
                        emailService.envia(emailManifestante);
                    }
                }
                MensagemFaceUtil.info("Manifestação encaminhada com sucesso.", "Manifestação encaminhada com sucesso.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                MensagemFaceUtil.alerta("Manifestação encaminhada mas não possível notiticar por e-mail.", "O seu encaminhamento foi realizado com sucesso porém, não foi possível notificar os envolvidos por e-mail.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            MensagemFaceUtil.erro("Erro ao encaminhar Manifestação.", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    ajustaListaStatusManifestacao();
    preparaListaAreasSolucionadoras();
    mountTabs();
    //zerando variaveis
    idUnidadeEncaminhamento = null;
    idUsuarioEncaminhamento = null;
    mensagemEncaminhamento = null;
    dsEncaminhamento = null;
    idEncaminhamentoPadronizado = null;
    arquivosEncaminhamento = new ArrayList<>();

    showRedirectPageModal();
}
```

Ela é chamada quando uma manifestação é encaminhada para uma unidade, porém no primeiro encaminhamento ocorre tudo ok, mas se tento encaminhar uma segunda manifestação para o mesmo órgão este retorna a mensagem do catch de "Erro ao encaminhar Manifestação.".

No log imprime o seguinte erro:

```
13:50:46,298 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-2) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23505
13:50:46,298 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-2) ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_6w9ft31ycpj6j9pf1b17k8nw2"
  Detalhe: Key (tbclassificacao_idclassificacao)=(2177) already exists.
13:50:46,300 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-2) javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
13:50:46,300 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-2)    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
```

E após estes segue com um monte de mensagens genéricas que nem cabem aqui na caixa de texto, mas pode ser visto aqui: https://pastebin.com/6Lfs8Z6F

A tbClassificacao que está no log é essa:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package br.com.xti.ouvidoria.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

/**
 *
 * @author samuel.guimaraes
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbClassificacao")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "TbClassificacao.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM TbClassificacao t"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "TbClassificacao.findByIdClassificacao", query = "SELECT t FROM TbClassificacao t WHERE t.idClassificacao = :idClassificacao"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "TbClassificacao.findByUnidade", query = "SELECT t FROM TbClassificacao t WHERE :idUnidade MEMBER OF t.tbUnidadeCollection"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "TbClassificacao.findByDsClassificacao", query = "SELECT t FROM TbClassificacao t WHERE t.dsClassificacao = :dsClassificacao")})
public class TbClassificacao implements Serializable, Comparable<TbClassificacao> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idClassificacao")
    private Integer idClassificacao;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 180)
    @Column(name = "dsClassificacao")
    private String dsClassificacao;
    @OneToMany
    private Collection<TbUnidade> tbUnidadeCollection = new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name="tbClassificacao_tbSubClassificacao",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="TbClassificacao_idClassificacao", referencedColumnName="idClassificacao")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="tbSubClassificacaoCollection_idSubClassificacao", referencedColumnName="idSubClassificacao")})
    private Collection<TbSubClassificacao> tbSubClassificacaoCollection = new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name="tbManifestacao_tbClassificacao",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="tbClassificacao_idClassificacao", referencedColumnName="idClassificacao")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="TbManifestacao_idManifestacao", referencedColumnName="idManifestacao")})
    private Collection<TbManifestacao> tbManifestacaoCollection = new ArrayList<>();


    public Collection<TbUnidade> getTbUnidadeCollection() {
        return tbUnidadeCollection;
    }

    public Collection<TbManifestacao> getTbManifestacaoCollection() {
        return tbManifestacaoCollection;
    }

    public void setTbManifestacaoCollection(Collection<TbManifestacao> tbManifestacaoCollection) {
        this.tbManifestacaoCollection = tbManifestacaoCollection;
    }

    public void setTbUnidadeCollection(Collection<TbUnidade> tbUnidadeCollection) {
        this.tbUnidadeCollection = tbUnidadeCollection;
    }

    public TbClassificacao() {
    }

    public TbClassificacao(Integer idClassificacao) {
        this.idClassificacao = idClassificacao;
    }

    public TbClassificacao(Integer idClassificacao, String dsClassificacao) {
        this.idClassificacao = idClassificacao;
        this.dsClassificacao = dsClassificacao;
    }

    public Integer getIdClassificacao() {
        return idClassificacao;
    }

    public void setIdClassificacao(Integer idClassificacao) {
        this.idClassificacao = idClassificacao;
    }

    public String getDsClassificacao() {
        return dsClassificacao;
    }

    public void setDsClassificacao(String dsClassificacao) {
        this.dsClassificacao = dsClassificacao;
    }

    public Collection<TbSubClassificacao> getTbSubClassificacaoCollection() {
        return tbSubClassificacaoCollection;
    }

    public void setTbSubClassificacaoCollection(Collection<TbSubClassificacao> tbSubClassificacaoCollection) {
        this.tbSubClassificacaoCollection = tbSubClassificacaoCollection;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (idClassificacao != null ? idClassificacao.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (!(object instanceof TbClassificacao)) {
            return false;
        }
        TbClassificacao other = (TbClassificacao) object;
        if ((this.idClassificacao == null && other.idClassificacao != null) || (this.idClassificacao != null && !this.idClassificacao.equals(other.idClassificacao))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s > %s", getEntidade(), getDescricao());
    }

    private String getEntidade() {
        return "Classificação";
    }

    private String getDescricao() {
        return dsClassificacao;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(TbClassificacao o) {
        return getDsClassificacao().toUpperCase().compareTo(o.getDsClassificacao().toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Estou estranhando muito, a principio era para ser um projeto que estão utilizando e deveria ser apenas instalar e utilizar.
Se alguém quiser conferir o projeto é este: https://github.com/culturagovbr/GOG

**Atualização!**

Através dos comentários e de alguns testes encontrei um código no script de carga inicial de dados encontrado no próprio projeto deles que exclui e então cria de forma manual a `tbclassificacao_tbunidade`, tabela que realiza um join com a `tbclassificacao` e onde ocorre o erro.

```
--Acertos nos mapeamentos gerados

DROP TABLE tbclassificacao_tbunidade;

CREATE TABLE tbclassificacao_tbunidade
(
  tbclassificacao_idclassificacao integer NOT NULL,
  tbunidadecollection_idunidade integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk107ce929d7b9b0e FOREIGN KEY (tbclassificacao_idclassificacao)
      REFERENCES tbclassificacao (idclassificacao) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk107ce92d27d48b9 FOREIGN KEY (tbunidadecollection_idunidade)
      REFERENCES tbunidade (idunidade) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT tbclassificacao_tbunidade_tbclassificacao_idclassificacao_key UNIQUE (tbclassificacao_idclassificacao, tbunidadecollection_idunidade)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

**Obs: Sem rodar este comando ele nem compila.**

Comment: Já tentou alterar na `tbClassificacao` a linha `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` para `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` ?

Comment: Tentei aqui @WéllingthonM.deSouza, mas mesma coisa

Comment: Na verdade com esta modificação ao inserir os dados no banco indica um erro `ERROR:  relation "tbclassificacao_idclassificacao_seq" does not exist
********** Error **********`

Comment: E caso eu exclua a linha `ALTER SEQUENCE tbclassificacao_idclassificacao_seq RESTART WITH 5325;` para evitar o erro, então não acessa o cadastro de manifestações

Comment: informe o primeiro `erro` completo.

Comment: veja se essa resposta no [soEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11316361/8353154) pode resolver esse problema do primeiro erro.

Comment: Não me ajuda pois o meu problema está na falta de conhecimento de JSP, e a criação é feita pelo hibernate e não diretamente por SQL

Comment: Esse erro não tem relação com JSP. Precisa encontrar onde você está salvando essa `TbClassificacao`, coloque o resto do stack trace que lá deve apontar o local exato. Outra coisa, esse `ALTER SEQUENCE...` parece indicar que na tabela já existam outras linhas nessa tabela. Se você reinicia o contador e tenta inserir de novo o mesmo `idclassificacao`, vai dar erro mesmo.

Comment: Adicionei um script a questão acima pois descobri que o erro não é na `TbClassificacao` e sim na `tbManifestacao_tbClassificacao` a qual realiza um `join` com a `TbClassificacao`

Comment: @Dudaskank a questão é que várias manifestações podem ser enviadas contendo a mesma classificação, por isso que não poderia existir este erro

Comment: Rapaz, esses nomes confundem... Este script da atualização, você rodou ele já? Segundo ele, a chave única é composta por 2 campos, porém o erro indica que a chave única é só no campo `tbclassificacao_idclassificacao`. E sobre o erro de acesso na tela de manifestações, veja se isso ajuda: https://github.com/culturagovbr/GOG/issues/33

Comment: @Dudaskank esse é outro erro que já tive que enfrentar antes e já resolvi

Comment: @Dudaskank sim esse script faz parte do processo de instalação

Comment: O log de erros completo pode ser visto aqui: https://pastebin.com/6Lfs8Z6F

Comment: Esses nomes... se você olhar com atenção, ele mostra o nome da constraint naquele trecho de erro: "uk_6w9ft31ycpj6j9pf1b17k8nw2". Nesse script, o nome da constraint é outro, "tbclassificacao_tbunidade_tbclassificacao_idclassificacao_key", então não é nessa tabela do script que deu erro.

Comment: Procure esse nome "uk_6w9ft31ycpj6j9pf1b17k8nw2" no script de instalação e veja se está lá. Se não estiver, veja no postgresql se encontra a tabela desse índice.

Comment: @Dudaskank apesar de não estar ali no script o SGBD cria, se ver o código de criação atribuido pelo SGBD a tabela `tbManifestacao_tbClassificacao` está lá `CONSTRAINT uk_6w9ft31ycpj6j9pf1b17k8nw2 UNIQUE (tbclassificacao_idclassificacao),`

Comment: @Dudaskank pode ver aqui https://pastebin.com/XswRHjSN

Comment: @Dudaskank erro meu vc estava falando da `tbclassificacao_tbunidade`e eu da `tbmanifestacao_tbclassificacao`

Comment: @Dudaskank muito obrigado, esse seu ultimo comentário me ajudou a resolver o erro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, com a muita análise e ajuda de todos que comentaram realmente ficou evidente o erro no fato dq na tabela `tbmanifestacao_tbclassificacao` o campo `tbclassificacao_idclassificacao` não poderia ter como requisito ser `UNIQUE` pois mais de uma manifestação com classificação selecionada igual podem ser encaminhadas para a mesma unidade e esta tabela armazena a classificação escolhida com relação a manifestação.

Assim testei a criação da tabela retirando todas estas dependências, e o encaminhamento funcionou.

Como era:

```
-- Table: public.tbmanifestacao_tbclassificacao

-- DROP TABLE public.tbmanifestacao_tbclassificacao;

CREATE TABLE public.tbmanifestacao_tbclassificacao
(
  tbmanifestacao_idmanifestacao integer NOT NULL,
  tbclassificacao_idclassificacao integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_6w9ft31ycpj6j9pf1b17k8nw2 FOREIGN KEY (tbclassificacao_idclassificacao)
      REFERENCES public.tbclassificacao (idclassificacao) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_jbkoiljnamdf9icojnuxaskby FOREIGN KEY (tbmanifestacao_idmanifestacao)
      REFERENCES public.tbmanifestacao (idmanifestacao) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT uk_6w9ft31ycpj6j9pf1b17k8nw2 UNIQUE (tbclassificacao_idclassificacao),
  CONSTRAINT uk_jbkoiljnamdf9icojnuxaskby UNIQUE (tbmanifestacao_idmanifestacao)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.tbmanifestacao_tbclassificacao
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Como fiz:

```
-- Table: public.tbmanifestacao_tbclassificacao

-- DROP TABLE public.tbmanifestacao_tbclassificacao;

CREATE TABLE public.tbmanifestacao_tbclassificacao
(
  tbmanifestacao_idmanifestacao integer NOT NULL,
  tbclassificacao_idclassificacao integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_6w9ft31ycpj6j9pf1b17k8nw2 FOREIGN KEY (tbclassificacao_idclassificacao)
      REFERENCES public.tbclassificacao (idclassificacao) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_jbkoiljnamdf9icojnuxaskby FOREIGN KEY (tbmanifestacao_idmanifestacao)
      REFERENCES public.tbmanifestacao (idmanifestacao) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT uk_jbkoiljnamdf9icojnuxaskby UNIQUE (tbmanifestacao_idmanifestacao)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.tbmanifestacao_tbclassificacao
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Bom que arrumou. Mas note que, se houver uma manifestação com por exemplo 2 classificações, o erro voltará, pois tem uma constraint ali que diz só pode haver um tbmanifestacao_idmanifestacao de cada nessa tabela.

Comment: @Dudaskank quanto a isso está certo pois a classificação serve como um filtro para o encaminhamento, sendo assim só pode ser selecionada uma classificação, e a nível de interface não tem como selecionar mais

Comment: @Dudaskank esses nomes q eles utilizaram confundem muito mesmo, pretendo modificar, mas seria algo como: unidade = Fundação Municipal de Esportes, classificação = Escolinhas, sub-classificação = Escolinha de Volei, e assim o ouvidor encaminha ao responsável mais próximo do alvo dentro desta hierarquia